# Cascade in Rebol

Tags: metaprogramming, rebol

In Logo Language, [`cascade`](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~bh/v1ch5/hof.html) is a procedure to to compose a function with itself several times (it is almost like `fold` in functional language).
Example:

```
   add 4 add 4 add 4 5  -->  cascade 3 [add 4 ?1] 5 ==  17
   2^8 -->  cascade 8 [?1 * 2] 1
   fibonacci 5 --> (cascade 5 [?1 + ?2] 1 [?1] 0)
   factorial 5 --> (cascade 5 [?1 * ?2] 1 [?2 + 1] 1)
```

General notation for multi-input cascade, in Logo:
(cascade how many function1 start1 function2 start2 ...) with:

```
function1 -> ?1 ,  
function2 -> ?2 ...
```

Cascade returns the final value of ?1.

In Rebol:

```
cascade1: func [howmany function1 start1] [....]      
cascade2: func [howmany function1 start1 function2 start2] [....]
```

How to write cascade1 and cascade2 in Rebol ?

Answer (score 2):

With [bind](http://www.rebol.com/docs/words/wbind.html), that Binds words to a specified context (in this case local context of function), and [compose](http://www.rebol.com/docs/words/wcompose.html) function, I get:

```
cascade: func [  
    times
    template
    start 
] [
    use [?1] [
        ?1: start  
        template: compose [?1: (template)]  
        loop times bind template '?1  
        ?1
    ]  
]

cascade 8 [?1 * 2] 1
== 256
cascade 3 [add 4 ?1] 5
== 17  
val: 4
cascade 3 [add val ?1] 5
== 17



cascade2: func [
    times
    template1 start1
    template2 start2
    /local **temp**
] [
    use [?1 ?2] [ ; to bind only ?1 and ?2 and to avoid variable capture
        ?1: start1
        ?2: start2
        loop 
            times 
            bind 
                compose [**temp**: (template1) ?2: (template2) ?1: **temp**] 
                '?1
        ?1
    ]
]


 cascade2 5 [?1 * ?2] 1 [?2 + 1] 1
 == 120
 cascade2 5 [?1 + ?2] 1 [?1] 0
 == 8
```

Answer (score 2):

My answer uses REBOL 3, but could be backported to 2 without too much trouble. (I'd have done it in REBOL 2, but I don't have REBOL 2 on my system and haven't used it in a long time.) This implements `cascade` *fully* (i.e., with any number of "functions") and does it in an idiomatically REBOL kind of way: It uses a simple DSL.

```
cascade: funct [
  count [integer!]
  template [block!]
  /only "Don't reduce TEMPLATE"
  /local arg fun-block
][
  param-list: copy []
  param-number: 1
  arg-list: copy []
  fun-list: copy []
  template-rules: [
    some [
      copy fun-block block! (
        append param-list to word! rejoin ["?" ++ param-number]
        append fun-list fun-block
      )
      copy arg any-type! (
        append arg-list :arg
      )
    ]
    end
  ]
  unless only [template: reduce template]
  unless parse template template-rules [
    do make error! rejoin ["The template " mold/flat template " contained invalid syntax."]
  ]
  while [! tail? fun-list] [
    fun-list: change fun-list func param-list first fun-list
  ]
  fun-list: head fun-list
  loop count [
    temp-args: copy []
    for f 1 length? fun-list 1 [
      append/only temp-args apply pick fun-list f arg-list
    ]
    arg-list: copy temp-args
  ]
  first arg-list
]
```

Using it is simple:

```
print cascade 23 [[?1 + ?2] 1 [?1] 0]
```

This correctly gives the value `46368` from one of the `cascade` examples given in the Logo `cascade` documentation linked by the questioner. The syntax of the DSL should be brutally obvious. It's a series of blocks followed by starting arguments. The outer block is reduced unless the `/only` refinement is used. A block itself will work just fine as an argument, e.g.,

```
cascade 5 [[?1] [1 2 3]]
```

This is because the first block is interpreted as a "function", the second as a starting argument, the third as a "function" and so on until the template block is exhausted.

As far as I can tell, this is a complete (and rather elegant) implementation of `cascade`. Man, I love REBOL. What a shame this language didn't take off.

Comment: I like this quite a bit and will be adding it to my REBOL 3 Swiss army knife of functions which you can find at https://github.com/Revolucent/rebol. Note that these are REBOL 3 modules.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a somewhat working `cascade` in Rebol. It won't work with `op!` datatype--i.e. `+`, `*`--but it will work with `add` and `multiply`.  You may want to check out the [higher order functions script](http://www.rebol.org/view-script.r?script=hof.r) to see some other examples.  I haven't had time to write `cascade2` yet

```
cascade: func [
    times [integer!]
    f [any-function!]
    partial-args [series!]
    last-arg
][
    expression: copy reduce [last-arg]
    repeat n times [
        insert head expression partial-args
        insert head expression get 'f
    ]
    expression
]
```

With your examples:

```
probe cascade 3 :add [4] 5
print cascade 3 :add [4] 5
```

will result in:

```
[make action! [[
        "Returns the addition of two values."
        value1 [scalar! date!]
        value2
    ]] 4 make action! [[
        "Returns the addition of two values."
        value1 [scalar! date!]
        value2
    ]] 4 make action! [[
        "Returns the addition of two values."
        value1 [scalar! date!]
        value2
    ]] 4 5]

17
```

and

```
probe cascade 8 :multiply [2] 1
print cascade 8 :multiply [2] 1
```

Will result in:

```
[make action! [[
        "Returns the first value multiplied by the second."
        value1 [scalar!]
        value2 [scalar!]
    ]] 2 make action! [[
        "Returns the first value multiplied by the second."
        value1 [scalar!]
        value2 [scalar!]
    ]] 2 make action! [[
        "Returns the first value multiplied by the second."
        value1 [scalar!]
        value2 [scalar!]
    ]] 2 make action! [[
        "Returns the first value multiplied by the second."
        value1 [scalar!]
        value2 [scalar!]
    ]] 2 make action! [[
        "Returns the first value multiplied by the second."
        value1 [scalar!]
        value2 [scalar!]
    ]] 2 make action! [[
        "Returns the first value multiplied by the second."
        value1 [scalar!]
        value2 [scalar!]
    ]] 2 make action! [[
        "Returns the first value multiplied by the second."
        value1 [scalar!]
        value2 [scalar!]
    ]] 2 make action! [[
        "Returns the first value multiplied by the second."
        value1 [scalar!]
        value2 [scalar!]
    ]] 2 1]

256
```